# Arduino Pro Micro clone clock cycle issue

Tags: arduino-pro-micro

I have several Arduino Pro Micro clones that are giving me an issue where they work immediately after being programmed while the USB cable is still connected, but as soon as I disconnect and reconnect the USB cable the program fails. I was able to break it down to the simplest form and found that the clock cycle is off by what I estimate to be almost a factor of 10.

For testing, the only command in the loop is `Serial.println(millis());`. Immediately after programming you can watch the milliseconds scroll by in the serial monitor at the expected rate. Unplug and plug the USB, reconnect the serial monitor and now the milliseconds scroll by at about 1 second interval.

The Arduino IDE version is 1.6.8 and have tested it from both a Mac and Ubuntu with the same results. Also tested on 4 different boards with the same results. I also tested the latest Arduino beta with no change. Next I'm going to download some older Arduino IDE versions.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The fix for this issue was to reload the bootloader.  I used the [SparkFun Caterina bootloader](https://github.com/sparkfun/Arduino_Boards/tree/master/sparkfun/avr/bootloaders/caterina).